# Extend a Jquery object recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to extend a javascript object in a repeatable fashion without having to iterate through my element too much.  This is a very simple example to illustrate the question:

```
var test1 = [
            {
              tests: [
                {
                  label: "this is a test"
                },
                {
                  label: "this is a test"
                },
                {
                  label: "this is a test"
                }
              ]}];

var test2 = [
            {
              tests: [
                  {comments: 'this is a comment'}
              ]}];

console.log($.extend(true, test1, test2))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76bBR/3/

The way it works now the comment item will only apply to the first element in test1.  I am wondering if there is a nifty way to do this such that it applies to all without having to do forEach.  Obviously in this small case forEach will be fine, but in my real example I have a very deep object with several lists which I want to merge with static data for each of the items.  Are there any cool tools out there which make this easy?

```
var idealResult = [
            {
              tests: [
                {
                  label: "this is a test",
                  comments: 'this is a comment'
                },
                {
                  label: "this is a test",
                  comments: 'this is a comment'
                },
                {
                  label: "this is a test",
                  comments: 'this is a comment'
                }
              ]}];
```

Comment: you'll have to do your own cloning.

Comment: you can use Object.create() or OOP-like inheritance, or you can iterate and tack-on one-at-a-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried playing around with a recursive algorithm, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76bBR/12/).

```
function recursiveAppend(src, dest) {
    // If it's an array, loop through elements
    if ($.isArray(src)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
            // If function returns true, then it found the 'deepest' level...
            if ( recursiveAppend(src[i], dest[i]) ) {
                // ...so extend all objects in the destination...
                for (var j = 0; j < dest.length; j++) {
                    $.extend(true, dest[j], src[i]);
                }
                // ...and stop looping
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // If it's an object, loop through keys
    else if ($.isPlainObject(src)) {
        for (var key in src) {
            if (src.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                // Check if the destination has the key
                if (dest.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    return recursiveAppend(src[key], dest[key])
                }
                // If it doesn't, then we found the 'deepest' level
                else {
                    //debugger;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //debugger;
        return true;
    }
};
```

This algorithm makes the assumption that your `src` and `dest` have the same structure (regardless of what it is) until the deepest level, where `dest` will then consist of an array of objects analogous to `src`'s single object.

It also stops after it finds the **first** non-array/non-object key.

It's not fully tested, so throw a lot of random test cases at it! You'll want to add protections against `src` and `dest` being different structures (I always assume there will be corresponding pairs of `src[i]`, `dest[i]` or `src[key]`, `dest[key]`).

Hopefully this points you in the right direction =)

Comment: This is definitely putting me on the right path, thank you.  I can depend on the fact that the arrays will have the same structure so no issue there.

Comment: @Korra No problem, just make sure to test a lot of different cases! Also, accept the answer if it works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like so? http://jsfiddle.net/76bBR/5/

```
console.log(test1.concat(test2))
```

Maybe you'll find something usable here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array